# Stanford dependency parser can not deal with some Chinese sentences

Tags: parsing, dependencies, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm parsing a set of Chinese sentences. Usually Stanford parser works well, but

1. in special cases, such as '柴油机 可燃混合气 的 形成 和 燃烧 都 是 直接 在 燃烧室内 进行 的 。' and '在 日常 行驶 中 肯定 不 可能 保持 燃油量 的 多少 ， 乘客 的 胖 瘦 ， 直接 影响 到 前后轴 的 配重 问题 。'.  They are well-formed, but NullPointerException in line'List tdl = gs .typedDependenciesCCprocessed();', which copied from Demo.java.
2. I notice that even the program runs correctly, the output of dependency parsing misses something, say '[advmod(传统-3, 这种-2), amod(范畴-6, 传统-3), nn(范畴-6, 油门-4), nn(范畴-6, 应用-5), dep(限制-8, 受到-7), root(ROOT-0, 限制-8), dep(精确性-11, 缺乏-10), conj_并(限制-8, 精确性-11), nn(形势-18, 汽车电子技术-16), nn(形势-18, 发展-17), num(电子油门-23, 一-21), dep(一-21, 种-22), dep(egas-25, （-24), dep(电子油门-23, egas-25), dep(egas-25, ）-26)]', it can be seen that no '-1', '-9', '-12', '-13', '-14', '-15', '19' in the dependency parsing result. The corresponding original sentence is '但 这种 传统 油门 应用 范畴 受到 限制 并 缺乏 精确性 ， 在 日新月异 的 汽车电子技术 发展 形势 下 ， 一 种 电子油门 （ egas ） 应运而生 。', if you need.

How to fix them. Thanks.

Comment: On the scale of one to ten of "is it too localized", this question scores eleven :)

Comment: Why?  Could be a well-known bug in the Stanford parser..

Comment: I change another dependency parser for help, HIT's LTP platform, it works. But LTP and StanfordParser use different dependency parsing strategies.

Comment: i guess the stanford parser user/dev mailing list (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml#Mail) would be a better platform to request for help. It looks like a bug.